# How to export a temporary recordset to a csv file using vba

Tags: ms-access, vba, export-to-csv

I have a ms access table that is tracking 50 products with their daily sold volumes. I would like to export using vba 1 csv file (including headers) for each product showing the daily volumes from a recordset without saving the recordset to a permanent query. I am using the below code but I am stuck at the point of the actual export highlighted below in code. 
    Any assistance in fixing this is appreciated.

```
Dim rst As Recordset
Dim rstId As Recordset

    SQLExportIds = "SELECT DISTINCT tblDailyVols.SecId FROM tblDailyVols WHERE tblDailyVols.IsDeleted=False"
    Set rstId = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(SQLExportIds)
        If rstId.EOF = True Then
            MsgBox "No Products Found"
            Exit Sub
        End If

        Do While rstId.EOF = False
            SecId = rstId.Fields("SecId")
            SQLExportQuotes = " SELECT tblDailyVols.ID , tblDailyVols.TradedVolume, tblDailyVols.EffectiveDate  FROM tblDailyVols "
            SQLExportQuotes = SQLExportQuotes & " WHERE  tblDailyVols.IsDeleted=False and tblDailyVols.ID = " & SecId
            SQLExportQuotes = SQLExportQuotes & " ORDER BY tblDailyVols.EffectiveDate "


        Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(SQLExportQuotes)
            If rst.EOF = True Then
             MsgBox "No Quotes Found"
             Exit Sub
            End If

            IDFound = rst.Fields("ID")
            OutputPlace = “C:\Output”  & IDFound & ".csv"

            Set qdfTemp = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("", SQLExportQuotes)
            **DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, , 1, OutputPlace, True** <--This Here Line Fails
            Set rst = Nothing
          rstId.MoveNext
        Loop
        Set rstId = Nothing
```

Comment: AFAIK TransferText only works with named (=saved) queries.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will have to create an actual named QueryDef object for TransferText to work with, but then you can just delete it afterwards. Something like this:

```vbs
Set qdfTemp = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("zzzTemp", SQLExportQuotes)
Set qdfTemp = Nothing
DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, , "zzzTemp", OutputPlace, True
DoCmd.DeleteObject acQuery, "zzzTemp"
```

Comment: I want to distribute the front end db as an encryted accde, hence I want to minimize any object creation. Is it even possible to add a new query to an accde? @Hansup

Comment: Create the query once.  You can add it to the ACCDB before you create the ACCDE if you wish.  Afterwards, your VBA code need only modify the saved query's `.SQL` property.  But if you need to, you can create a saved query in an ACCDE.  The option is not available from the UI, but you can do it with code.

Comment: If you don't want the users to see the query in the navigation pane, give it a name which starts with "USys".  Then it will only be visible if they've chosen the option to display system objects.

Comment: @Lawrence Yes, the code in my answer will work when executed from within an .accde file.

Comment: Thank you very much. The Create & Delete Method is working in the accde, its actually quite fast. @Hans thats my daily learn-a-thing moment right there. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You asked for a VBA solution, and I detect a preference for not creating new Access objects; you may well have good reasons for that, but the 'pure' VBA solution is a lot of work.

A solution that implements encapsulating text fields in quotes is the bare minimum for a competent answer. After that, you need to address the three big issues:

1. Optimising away VBA's clunky string-handling;
2. The Byte Order Marker, which VBA embeds in every string it saves to
   file, ensuring that some of the most common consumers of a csv file
   cannot read it properly;
3. ...And there's rarely any middle ground between writing the file
   line-by-line, forever, and writing it in one big chunk that'll throw
   an out-of-memory error on larger recordsets.

Beginners in VBA may find the string-optimisations difficult to understand: the biggest performance gain available in native VBA is to avoid string allocation and concatenation ( here's why: http://www.aivosto.com/vbtips/stringopt2.html#huge ) - so I use join, split, and replace instead of `myString = MyString & MoreString`

The trailing loop, with the `RecordSet.GetRows()` call at the very end, will raise eyebrows among coders with strong opinions about structured programming: but there are constraints on how you can order the code so that the 'chunks' are concatenated into the file without any missed bytes, out-of-register shifts in the byte order, or blank lines.

So here goes:

```vb
 Public Function RecordsetToCSV(ByRef rst As ADODB.Recordset, _
                                ByRef OutputFile As String, _
                                Optional ByRef FieldList As Variant, _
                                Optional ByVal CoerceText As Boolean = True, _
                                Optional ByVal CleanupText As Boolean = True _
                                ) As Long

' Output a recordset to a csv file and returns the row count.

' If the output file is locked, or specified in an inaccessible location, the
' 'ByRef' OutputFile parameter becomes a file in the user's local temp folder

' You can supply your own field list. This isn't a substituted file header of
' aliased field names: it is a subset of the field names, which ADO will read
' selectively from the recordset. Each item in the list matches a named field

' CoerceText=TRUE will encapsulate all items, numeric or not, in quote marks.
' CleanupText=TRUE strips quotes and linefeeds from the data: FALSE is faster

' You should only set them FALSE if you're confident that the data is 'clean'
' with no quote marks, commas or line breaks in any unencapsulated text field

' This code handles unicode, and outputs a file that can be read by Microsoft
' ODBC and OLEDB database drivers by removing the Byte Order Marker.


On Error Resume Next

' Coding note: we're not doing any string-handling in VBA.Strings: allocating
' deallocating and (especially!) concatenating are SLOW. We are using the VBA
' Join and Split functions ONLY. Feel free to optimise further by declaring a
' faster set of string functions from the Kernel if you want to.
'
' Other optimisations: type pun. Byte Arrays are interchangeable with strings
' Some of our loops through these arrays have a 'step' of 2. This optimises a
' search-and-replace for ANSI chars in an array of 2-byte unicodes. Note that
' it's only used to remove known ANSI 'Latin' characters with a 'low' byte of
' zero: any other use of the two-byte 'step' will fail on non-Latin unicodes.

' ** THIS CODE IS IN THE PUBLIC DOMAIN **
'   Nigel Heffernan   Excellerando.Blogspot.com

Const FETCH_ROWS As Long = 4096

Dim COMMA As String * 1
Dim BLANK As String * 4
Dim EOROW As String * 2


 COMMA = ChrW$(44)
 BLANK = ChrW$(13) & ChrW$(10) & ChrW$(13) & ChrW$(10)
 EOROW = ChrW$(13) & ChrW$(10)


Dim FetchArray  As Variant

Dim i As Long ' i for rows in the output file, records in the recordset
Dim j As Long ' j for columns in the output file, fields in the recordset
Dim k As Long ' k for all other loops: bytes in individual data items

Dim i_Offset As Long

Dim i_LBound As Long
Dim i_UBound As Long
Dim j_LBound As Long
Dim j_UBound As Long
Dim k_lBound As Long
Dim k_uBound As Long

Dim hndFile  As Long
Dim varField As Variant

Dim iRowCount  As Long
Dim arrBytes() As Byte
Dim arrTemp1() As String
Dim arrTemp2() As String
Dim arrTemp3(0 To 2) As String

Dim boolNumeric As Boolean

Dim strHeader   As String
Dim arrHeader() As Byte

Dim strFile As String
Dim strPath As String
Dim strExtn As String

strFile = FileName(OutputFile)
strPath = FilePath(OutputFile)
strExtn = FileExtension(strFile)

If rst Is Nothing Then Exit Function
If rst.State <> 1 Then Exit Function


If strExtn = "" Then
    strExtn = ".csv"
End If


With FSO

    If strFile = "" Then
        strFile = .GetTempName
        strFile = Left(strFile, Len(strFile) - Len(".tmp"))
        strFile = strFile & strExtn
    End If

    If strPath = "" Then
        strPath = TempSQLFolder
    End If

    If Right(strPath, 1) <> "\" Then
        strPath = strPath & "\"
    End If

    strExtn = FileExtension(strFile)
    If strExtn = "" Then
        strExtn = ".csv"
        strFile = strFile & strExtn
    End If

    OutputFile = strPath & strFile

End With


If FileName(OutputFile) <> "" Then
    If Len(VBA.FileSystem.Dir(OutputFile, vbNormal)) <> 0 Then

        Err.Clear
        VBA.FileSystem.Kill OutputFile  ' do it now, and reduce wait for deletion
        If Err.Number = 70 Then  ' permission denied: change the output file name
            OutputFile = FileStripExtension(OutputFile) & "_" & FileStripExtension(FSO.GetTempName) & FileExtension(OutputFile)
        End If

    End If
End If


' ChrW$() gives a 2-byte 'Wide' char. This coerces all subsequent operations to UTF16

arrTemp3(0) = ChrW$(34)       ' Encapsulating quote
arrTemp3(1) = vbNullString    ' The field value will go here
arrTemp3(2) = ChrW$(34)       ' Encapsulating quote



If rst.EOF And rst.BOF Then
    FetchArray = Empty
ElseIf rst.EOF Then
    rst.MoveFirst
End If

' An empty recordset must still write a header row of field names: we put this in the
' output buffer and write it to the file before we start looping through the records.

ReDim FetchArray(0 To rst.Fields.Count, 0 To 0)

i_LBound = 0
i_UBound = 0

If IsMissing(FieldList) Then

    For j = LBound(FetchArray, 1) To UBound(FetchArray, 1) - 1 Step 1
        FetchArray(j, i_UBound) = rst.Fields(j).Name
    Next j

Else

    j = 0

    For Each varField In FieldList
        j_UBound = j_UBound + 1
    Next varField

    ReDim arrTemp2(j_LBound To j_UBound)
    For Each varField In FieldList
        FetchArray(j, i_UBound) = CStr(varField)
        j = j + 1
    Next varField

End If

ReDim arrTemp1(i_LBound To i_UBound)    ' arrTemp1 is the rowset we write to file
ReDim arrTemp2(j_LBound To j_UBound)    ' arrTemp2 represents a single record

Do Until IsEmpty(FetchArray)

    i_LBound = LBound(FetchArray, 2)
    i_UBound = UBound(FetchArray, 2)

    j_LBound = LBound(FetchArray, 1)
    j_UBound = UBound(FetchArray, 1)

    If UBound(arrTemp1) <> i_UBound + 1 Then
        ReDim arrTemp1(i_LBound To i_UBound + 1)
        arrTemp1(i_UBound + 1) = vbNullString   ' The 'Join' operation will insert a trailing row
    End If                                      ' delimiter here (Not required by the last chunk)

    If UBound(arrTemp2) <> j_UBound Then
        ReDim arrTemp2(j_LBound To j_UBound)
    End If


    ' Data body. This is heavily optimised to avoid VBA String functions with allocations

    For i = i_LBound To i_UBound Step 1

        ' If this is confusing... Were you expecting FetchArray(i,j)? i for row, j for column?
        ' FetchArray comes from RecordSet.GetRows(), which returns a TRANSPOSED array: i and j
        ' are still the field and record ordinals, row(i) and column(j) in the output file.

        For j = j_LBound To j_UBound

            If IsNull(FetchArray(j, i)) Then
                arrTemp2(j) = ""
            Else
                arrTemp2(j) = FetchArray(j, i)  ' confused? see he note above
            End If

            If CleanupText Or (i_UBound = 0) Then  ' (i_UBound=0): always clean up field names

                arrBytes = arrTemp2(j) ' Integer arithmetic is faster than string-handling for
                                       ' this: all VBA string operations require an allocation

                For k = LBound(arrBytes) To UBound(arrBytes) Step 2

                    Select Case arrBytes(k)
                    Case 10, 13, 9, 160
                        If arrBytes(k + 1) = 0 Then
                            arrBytes(k) = 32 ' replaces CR, LF, Tab, and non-breaking
                        End If               ' spaces with the standard ANSI space
                    Case 44
                        If Not CoerceText Then
                            If arrBytes(k + 1) = 0 Then
                                arrBytes(k) = 32 ' replace comma with the ANSI space
                            End If
                        End If
                    Case 34
                        If arrBytes(k + 1) = 0 Then
                            arrBytes(k) = 39  ' replaces double-quote with single quote
                        End If
                    End Select

                Next k

                arrTemp2(j) = arrTemp2(j)

            End If  ' cleanup


            If CoerceText Then  ' encapsulate all fields in quotes, numeric or not

               arrTemp3(1) = arrTemp2(j)
               arrTemp2(j) = Join$(arrTemp3, vbNullString)

            ElseIf (i = 0) And (i = i_UBound) Then ' always encapsulate field names

               arrTemp3(1) = arrTemp2(j)
               arrTemp2(j) = Join$(arrTemp3, vbNullString)

            Else ' selective encapsulation, leaving numeric fields unencapsulated:
                 ' we *could* do this by reading the ADODB field types: but that's
                 ' slower, and you may be 'caught out' by provider-specific types.


                arrBytes = arrTemp2(j)

                boolNumeric = True

                For k = LBound(arrBytes) To UBound(arrBytes) Step 2
                    If arrBytes(k) < 43 Or arrBytes(k) > 57 Then 

                        If arrBytes(k) <> 69 Then
                            boolNumeric = False
                            Exit For
                        Else
                            If k > UBound(arrBytes) - 5 Then
                                boolNumeric = False
                                Exit For
                            ElseIf arrBytes(k + 2) = 45 Then
                                ' detect "1.234E-05"
                            ElseIf arrBytes(k + 2) = 43 Then
                                ' detect "1.234E+05"
                            Else
                                boolNumeric = False
                                Exit For
                            End If
                        End If

                    End If
                Next k

                If boolNumeric Then
                   For k = 1 + LBound(arrBytes) To UBound(arrBytes) Step 2
                       If arrBytes(k) <> 0 Then
                           boolNumeric = False
                           Exit For
                       End If
                   Next k
                End If

               arrBytes = vbNullString

               If Not boolNumeric Then ' text field, encapsulate it
                   arrTemp3(1) = arrTemp2(j)
                   arrTemp2(j) = Join(arrTemp3, vbNullString)
               End If

            End If ' CoerceText

        Next j

       arrTemp1(i) = Join(arrTemp2, COMMA)

    Next i

    iRowCount = iRowCount + i - 2


    '   **** WHY WE 'PUT' A BYTE ARRAY INSTEAD OF A VBA STRING VARIABLE  **** ****
    '
    '       Put #hndFile, , StrConv(Join(arrTemp1, EOROW), vbUnicode)
    '       Put #hndFile, , Join(arrTemp1, EOROW)
    '
    '   If you pass unicode, Wide or UTF-16 string variables to PUT, it prepends a
    '   Unicode Byte Order Mark to the data which, when written to your file, will
    '   render the field names illegible to Microsoft's JET ODBC and ACE-OLEDB SQL
    '   drivers (which can actually read unicode field names, if the helpful label
    '   isn't in the way). The primeval 'PUT' statement writes a Byte array as-is.
    '
    '   **** **** **** **** **** **** **** **** **** **** **** **** **** **** ****


    arrBytes = Join$(arrTemp1, vbCrLf)


    If hndFile = 0 Then

        i_Offset = 1
        If Len(Dir(OutputFile)) > 0 Then
            VBA.FileSystem.Kill OutputFile
        End If

        WaitForFileDeletion OutputFile

        hndFile = FreeFile
        Open OutputFile For Binary Access Write As #hndFile

    End If


    Put #hndFile, i_Offset, arrBytes
    i_Offset = i_Offset + 1 + UBound(arrBytes)
    Erase arrBytes


    If rst.EOF Then
        Erase FetchArray
        FetchArray = Empty
    Else
        If IsMissing(FieldList) Then
            FetchArray = rst.GetRows(FETCH_ROWS)
        Else
            FetchArray = rst.GetRows(FETCH_ROWS, , FieldList)
        End If
    End If

Loop   ' until isempty(FetchArray)


If iRowCount < 1 Then  '
    iRowCount = 0      ' Row Count excludes the header
End If


RecordsetToCSV = iRowCount


ExitSub:

    On Error Resume Next

    If hndFile <> 0 Then
        Close #hndFile
    End If

    Erase arrBytes
    Erase arrTemp1
    Erase arrTemp2
    Exit Function

ErrSub:

    Resume ExitSub

End Function


Public Function FilePath(Path As String) As String
' Strip the filename from a path, leaving only the path to the folder
' The last char of this path will be the backslash

' This does not check for the existence or accessibility of the file:
' all we're doing here is string-handling


Dim strPath   As String
Dim arrPath() As String

Const BACKSLASH As String * 1 = "\"

strPath = Trim(Path)

If strPath = "" Then Exit Function
If Right$(strPath, 1) = BACKSLASH Then Exit Function

arrPath = Split(strPath, BACKSLASH)

If UBound(arrPath) = 0 Then          ' does not contain "\"
    FilePath = ""
Else
    arrPath(UBound(arrPath)) = vbNullString
    FilePath = Join$(arrPath, BACKSLASH)
End If

Erase arrPath

End Function


Public Function FileName(Path As String) As String
' Strip the folder and path from a file's path string, leaving only the file name

' This does not check for the existence or accessibility of the file:
' all we're doing here is string-handling

Dim strPath   As String
Dim arrPath() As String

Const BACKSLASH As String * 1 = "\"

strPath = Trim(Path)

If strPath = "" Then Exit Function
If Right$(strPath, 1) = BACKSLASH Then Exit Function

arrPath = Split(strPath, BACKSLASH)

If UBound(arrPath) = 0 Then          ' does not contain "\"
    FileName = Path
Else
    FileName = arrPath(UBound(arrPath))
End If

Erase arrPath

End Function


Public Function FileExtension(Path As String) As String
' Return the extension of the file

' This is just string-handling: no file or path validation is attempted
' The file extension is deemed to be whatever comes after the final '.'
' The extension is returned with the dot, eg: ".txt" not "txt"
' If no extension is detected, FileExtension returns an empty string


Dim strFile   As String
Dim arrFile() As String
Const DOT_EXT As String * 1 = "."

strFile = FileName(Path)
strFile = Trim(strFile)

If strFile = "" Then Exit Function
If Right$(strFile, 1) = DOT_EXT Then Exit Function


arrFile = Split(strFile, DOT_EXT)

If UBound(arrFile) = 0 Then          ' does not contain "\"
    FileExtension = vbNullString
Else
    FileExtension = arrFile(UBound(arrFile))
    FileExtension = Trim(FileExtension)
    If Len(FileExtension) > 0 Then
        FileExtension = DOT_EXT & FileExtension
    End If
End If

Erase arrFile

End Function


Public Function FileStripExtension(Path As String) As String
' Return the filename, with the extension removed

' This is just string-handling:  no file validation is attempted
' The file extension is deemed to be whatever comes after the final '.'
' Both the dot and the extension are removed


Dim strFile   As String
Dim arrFile() As String
Const DOT_EXT As String * 1 = "." 


strFile = FileName(Path)

If strFile = "" Then Exit Function
If Right$(strFile, 1) = DOT_EXT Then Exit Function


strFile = Trim(strFile)

arrFile = Split(strFile, DOT_EXT)

If UBound(arrFile) = 0 Then          ' does not contain "\"
    FileStripExtension = vbNullString
Else
    ReDim Preserve arrFile(LBound(arrFile) To UBound(arrFile) - 1)
    FileStripExtension = Join$(arrFile, DOT_EXT)
End If

Erase arrFile

End Function
```

You'll also need the three path-and-file-name utility functions, if you don't have your own versions already:

- FileName()
- FilePath()
- FileStripExtension()

There's room for improvement in the string-encapsulation logic: the **correct** approach is to look up the recordset's field types and apply quote marks accordingly, and it may well turn out to be faster than my clunky byte-counting.

However, my approach is all about the file consumers and what they *expect* to see; and that doesn't always line up with what they *ought* to accept.

If you succeed in coding a faster and more robust version do, please, let me know: if I'm asked to, I may well code up encapsulation by field type myself.

Comment: If you insert `<!-- language: vb -->` , you get VBA syntax highlighting in the code.

Comment: @Andre  - I tried the  `<!-- language: vb -->` and removed it again: it changed the font, but did not apply any other formatting, and excluded the first three lines of code from the formatted block.  Feel free to edit the code yourself, and apply the tag: but do, please, restore the current formatting if this fails for you too. I look forward to hearing that the 'Stack is the first website. anywhere, ever,  to have succeeded in implementing a 'mock IDE'  formatting style that renders Visual Basic code from a user text-entry window on a web page: but today probably isn't that long-awaited day.

Comment: It muse be separated by blank lines from the text before and from the code after it, perhaps that was the issue.

Comment: @Andre  - Okay, that's a bit closer. Still needs a bit of help with  '>' '<'   as   &GT;  &LT;  and the comments aren't the comforting gangrenous green of the Office VBA IDE: but that's an improvement.

Answer (score 0):

just thought I would toss in; macros offer this feature - and it is quite simple to set up; 
select the export macro, select the query to export, select the format....  if you leave the destination selector blank it will launch the standard Windows file picker....

after a decade+ of coding in vba - macros have won me over for this particular function.....